# Shuffle Join in Hive optimisation and understanding

Tags: hadoop, join, mapreduce, hive, shuffle

Warning: Shuffle Join JOIN[38][tables = [a, b]] in Stage 'Stage-2:MAPRED' is a cross product

What does shuffle join mean?

What does JOIN[38][tables = [a, b]] signify? Does index 38 mean something special? Can I use this statement to reach the part of my query which needs optimisation?

PS : I have multiple shuffle joins happening in my query.